# Naive Bayess classifier probability out of range

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

While deriving Naive Bayess classifier formula, specifically on step
$$p(C | F_1,...,F_N) = \frac{(\prod_{i=1}^{N}p(F_i|C)) p(C)}{p(F_1,...,F_N)}$$
such an idea came to me: what if $F_1,...,F_N$ are pairwise independent events, then$$p(C | F_1,...,F_N) = \frac{(\prod_{i=1}^{N}p(F_i|C)) p(C)}{\prod_{i=1}^{N}p(F_i)} = \Big(\prod_{i=1}^{N}(\frac{p(F_i | C)}{p(F_i)}\Big)p(C)$$
but then if $p(F_i | C) > p(F_i)$ we have product of $N$ number larger than 1, so if $N$ is sufficiently large, this product can be arbitrary large and whole expression can be greater than 1, which cannot happen to probability.

Obviously, I'm wrong somewhere, but I cannot see where, can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you meant what if F<sub>1</sub>,...,F<sub>n</sub> are mutually independent. 
Secondly, think about it this way, if p(F<sub>i</sub>|C<sub>k</sub>) is really high, but p(F<sub>i</sub>) is really low, what does that tell you about p(C<sub>k</sub>)? It would have to be really low. More formally, use Bayes rule for p(F<sub>i</sub>|C<sub>k</sub>).

p(F<sub>i</sub>|C<sub>k</sub>)=$\frac{p(F_i)}{p(C_k)}p(C_k|F_i)$


$\frac{p(F_i|C_k)}{p(F_i)}$=$\frac{p(C_k|F_i)}{p(C_k)}$


Now let $p(F_i|C_k)=\epsilon$ and $p(F_i|C_k)=1-\epsilon$ for some arbitrary $\epsilon$ between 0 and 1.

$\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}=\frac{p(C_k|F_i)}{p(C_k)}$


$(1-\epsilon)p(C_k) = \epsilon p(C_k|F_i)$

Now you have it, if epsilon is super small, then

$p(C_k) \approx \epsilon p(C_k|F_i)$

So the $p(C_k)$ term would ensure that the final probability is less than or equal to 1.